# Highcharts: How to use both axis - bar coming from y axis and spine coming from the x

Tags: highcharts

I was wonder if anybody know how to have 2 graphs (using 2 axis) in highcharts, as it have a normal spine graph on the x axis and a bar graph on the opposite y axis?

I currently have a graph with a spline and a column graph on it but i was asked if i could move the columns so they are coming in from the right?

See the splines are bands of information while the bars are totals so they only really need one axis, while the spines use both band number and amount.

I would like to have those columns coming from the y axis on the right.

I have tried multiple x axis and y axis but when i change to 'bars' rather than 'columns' it flips both the bar and the spine graph to the right y axis.

Ideally I'd like the spine on the bottom x axis and the bars on the right y axis.

Hopefully one of you can help me

Comment: Can you post an example of how you would like it to look?  When you set a chart as a bar chart, it flips the axes, so the x axis is the vertical axis, and y axis is horizontal.  You should be able to do what you want if you keep this in mind and build your data structure accordingly, but I can't quite visualize what you are describing.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Its a dynamic graph so its difficult to do up a jfiddle but i've uploaded an image of how it looks and how i want it to look at http://i.imgur.com/nR9gAQf.jpg thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as noted, there is no setting in Highcharts to do this with one chart.

With 2 separate charts and a little CSS work, however, this is quite doable.

The idea is to build a line chart in one div, build a bar chart in a second div, put them both inside a wrapper, and use CSS positioning (and the chart's margin settings) to line them up appropriately.

Something like this:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin:1em auto;
    padding:0;
    width:900px;
}
#line-chart {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:400px;
}
#bar-chart {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:200px;
    height:400px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ea5bf1j5/

I use this approach for displaying a histogram of the time series being observed.

You can play with the positioning and transparency, of course, and set it up any number of ways.

Example with the bars on the left, overlayed:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ea5bf1j5/8/

Comment: Thanks, great work around. In the end they were happy enough with the columns but thanks anyway -- will be great to reference in future

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported in highcharts, so you need have always the same orientation of axis.